# New to me Chromebook, that wants linux without crouton

Tags: chromebook

I'm running a samsung chromebook xe500c21 with a intel atom inside and was wondering the best way to get ubuntu on it? Or remix os for that matter on it? Without using the crouton.

Comment: Basic idea in a nutshell: create recovery USB for your Chromebook( in case you funk things up ), create second USD stick with Ubuntu installation on it ( you will need a PC or mac to create both USB, by the way) , enable developer mode on Chromebook, and boot from installation usb

Comment: On Acer there used to be write protection screw inside, had to remove that, but i don't know about your Chromebook, so google up info about it